# Solving for variable with Gamma and Exponential Function

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve for the `dl` parameter knowing all the remaining variables and as `t->Infinity` or very large number

```
m = 1.000001; a = 0.566837276858827; q1 = 35931.22171;
(E^(dl+a dl^(-1+m) Gamma[1-m,dl]-a dl^(-1+m) Gamma[1-m,dl t]) q1)/a ==25000
```

*Mathematica* responds with unsolvable with methods available. All variables are positive ($>0$).

**Is there anyway to simplify this equation? Only real values are of interest.**

Comment: It's not clear that the function results in values equaling 25000 actually exist for `t` much greater than 1.2.  Consider looking at the contour plot:  `ContourPlot[(E^(dl + a dl^(-1 + m) Gamma[1 - m, dl] - 
       a dl^(-1 + m) Gamma[1 - m, dl t]) q1)/a,
 {dl, -5, 2}, {t, 0, 2}, Contours -> {25000}, ContourShading -> None,
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18] &) /@ {"dl", "t"},
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100]`

Comment: Could try `FindRoot`, if you have a ballpark estimate for a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

The answer might be that there is no solution for large values of $t$ if you want the functions value to be 25,000.  Here is a contour plot of the function for values of `t` and `dl`:

```
m = 1.000001; a = 0.566837276858827; q1 = 35931.22171;
ContourPlot[(E^(dl + a dl^(-1 + m) Gamma[1 - m, dl] - a dl^(-1 + m) Gamma[1 - m, dl t]) q1)/a,
 {dl, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 0.4},
 Contours -> {20000, 25000, 30000}, ContourLabels -> True, 
 ContourShading -> None,
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18] &) /@ {"dl", "t"},
 PlotRange -> {All, {0, 0.4}}, PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}},
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: Contour plot]

Once $t>0.2$, the values of the function are well over 25,000.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at it.  If `dl` and `t` are both positive and real, then `Gamma[1 - m, dl t]` essentially goes to `0` as `t -> ∞` as shown by plotting.

```
m = 1000001/1000000;
a = 566837276858827/1000000000000000;
q1 = 3593122171/100000;
```

I use exact values so MMa doesn't create small imaginary results which messes up the plots.

```
Plot[Gamma[1 - m, dlt], {dlt, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

That term damps out at about `dl*t = 15`, so for large `t` we simplify your equation by throwing out the portion containing `dl*t`

Moving everything to one side we can form the function

```
fn[dl_]:= (E^(dl + a*dl^(-1 + m)*Gamma[1 - m, dl])*q1)/a - 25000
```

A plot shows that there are no positive roots for the function.

```
Plot[N[fn[dl]], {dl, .01, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 200000}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

[image]